# Issue with query results from an SQL join question. Basic Question

Tags: sql

I have two tables, with the below layouts

**persons**:

```
person_id,
first_name,
last_name,
gender,
birth_date,
street,
town,
county
```

**likes**:

```
person_id,
food
```

I'm attempting to "List the names of those who do not like beer" from the above two tables, using just JOINS (I'm not allowed to use Subqueries).

The below code works fine if I change the WHERE clause to equals beer. It results in the two people who like beer.

But when I attempt to change it to those who don't like beer (it's not a real table, everybody likes beer ;)), the issue is it removes the exact row where the food preference is equal to beer. But the person who has other preferences like "pizza" but likes beer is still included.

The query is removing the relevant row for beer but not all the other rows related to this person.

How can I fix this without using a subquery?

```
SELECT 
    p1.first_name, p1.last_name, l1.food, l1.person_id

FROM
    persons AS p1
    JOIN likes AS l1
        ON p1.person_id = l1.person_id

WHERE l1.food <> "Beer"
```

For example, Aoife likes beer but also likes pizza. I want Aoife to be removed fully from the query results as she likes beer.

Comment: Note that `"beer"` refers to a column in standard SQL. String constants need to be enclosed in single quotes in SQL `'beer'` would be a string constant

Comment: When Aoife likes Beer and Pizza is this two rows in the table or there are two words in one column ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> List the names of those who do not like beer

You can use the `LEFT JOIN` antipattern:

```
SELECT p1.first_name, p1.last_name
FROM persons AS p1 
LEFT JOIN likes AS l1 ON p1.person_id = l1.person_id AND l1.food = 'Beer'
WHERE l1.person_id IS NULL
```

This attempts to join the each person with a record in `likes` with `food = 'Beer'`, and then filters on non-matching records only.

Another option is to use a `not exists` condition with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT p1.first_name, p1.last_name
FROM persons AS p1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM likes l1
    WHERE p1.person_id = l1.person_id AND l1.food = 'Beer'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you want a `left join` and to check that there are no matches.  This looks like:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM persons p LEFT JOIN
     likes l
     ON p.person_id = l.person_id AND l.food = 'Beer'
WHERE l.person_id IS NULL;  -- there is no match
```

You do not want to be including any information from `likes` in the `SELECT` clause -- the question is only asking for information about people.

A related query is:

```
select l.person_id
from likes l
group by l.person_id
having sum(case when l.food = 'beer' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

This returns people who have no `'beer'` in their list of likes.  But this only returns persons who have at least one `like`.  And some people may not like anything.